# Where is the land in Falkreath Hold in skyrim hearthfire

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I can't find the land that I bought in Falkreath Hold. Can anyone please tell me its location?

Comment: If you spoke to Jarl, did you not get a Map Marker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lakeview Manor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lakeview_Manor) is located to the east of Falkreath, approximately halfway between Falkreath and Helgen.

If you follow the road, you'll come across Pinewatch, turn north here and you'll find your land.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Manor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lakeview_Manor) is northeast of Falkreath. When you reach [Pinewatch](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lakeview_Manor), go north until you see Lakeview Manor. Didn't you get the map marker? If not, then keep reading.

[image]

You will find:

- Workbench
- Drafting Table
- Chest of supplies
- Anvil

If you still can't find the location, go [here](http://tamrielma.ps/skyrim/)